# R Dataframe : Date range Operations - Subset those rows which falls under a certain date range

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, subset, date-range

If you see my profile, all my questions are on dataframes and here is another!

I have a certain dataframe which is a result of a merge between Debit and Credit transactions

```
>head(allTxns)
   Cust_no    CreditDate   Credit     DebitDate   Debit
 1  12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-03    400
 2  12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-04    150
 3  12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-15    800     
 4  33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-04    50
 5  33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-05    504
 6  33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-06    332
 7  33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-08    56
 8  66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-04    150     
 9  66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-05    800
10  66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-11    400
11  66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-12    150
12  66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-13    800
```

My aim is to get those rows, where the DebitDate lies between 5 days of the CreditDate and hence I tried to subset the data, where I put the date range using the `:` operator

```
FiveDays <- allTxns$CreditDate+5 #Results in a vector which has date + 5 days

allTxns <- cbind(allTxns[1:2],FiveDays,allTxns[4:6]) #Adding the vector as a column of dataframe

newDf <- allTxns[allTxns$DebitDate %in% allTxns$CreditDate:allTxns$FiveDays]
```

In the above code, I'm getting the following logical error where only the first element is being used

```
Warning messages:
  1: In mer32$DepositDate:mer32$FiveDays2 :
      numerical expression has 3994 elements: only the first used
  2: In mer32$DepositDate:mer32$FiveDays2 :
      numerical expression has 3994 elements: only the first used
```

Hence my required output is getting limited only to the first Cust_no (12345) and not being applied to other rows. **How do I make sure that the range condition gets applied to ALL the rows??**

**Incorrect Output**

```
 >head(newDf)
 row.names  Cust_no    CreditDate   Credit     DebitDate   Debit
     1      12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-03    400
     2      12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-04    150
     4      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-04    50
     5      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-05    504
     6      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-06    332
     7      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-08    56
     8      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-04    150     
     9      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-05    800
    10      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-11    400
    11      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-12    150
    12      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-13    800
```

**Correct Output**

```
 >head(newDf)
 row.names  Cust_no    CreditDate   Credit     DebitDate   Debit
     1      12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-03    400
     2      12345     2014-10-01    200      2014-10-04    150
     4      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-04    50
     5      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-05    504
     6      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-06    332
     7      33344     2014-10-03    500      2014-10-08    56         
    10      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-11    400
    11      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-12    150
    12      66554     2014-10-10    660      2014-10-13    800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 allTxns[with(allTxns , CreditDate < DebitDate & DebitDate <=FiveDays),]
 #    Cust_no CreditDate   FiveDays Credit  DebitDate Debit
 #1    12345 2014-10-01 2014-10-06    200 2014-10-03   400
 #2    12345 2014-10-01 2014-10-06    200 2014-10-04   150
 #4    33344 2014-10-03 2014-10-08    500 2014-10-04    50
 #5    33344 2014-10-03 2014-10-08    500 2014-10-05   504
 #6    33344 2014-10-03 2014-10-08    500 2014-10-06   332
 #7    33344 2014-10-03 2014-10-08    500 2014-10-08    56
 #10   66554 2014-10-10 2014-10-15    660 2014-10-11   400
 #11   66554 2014-10-10 2014-10-15    660 2014-10-12   150
 #12   66554 2014-10-10 2014-10-15    660 2014-10-13   800
```

Answer (score 1):

This old questions already has an accepted answer. However, I noted that question and answer can be streamlined as it is *not* necessary to create the additional `FiveDays` column:

```
allTxns[with(allTxns, CreditDate <= DebitDate & DebitDate <= CreditDate + 5L), ]
```

> ```
>    Cust_no CreditDate Credit  DebitDate Debit
> 1    12345 2014-10-01    200 2014-10-03   400
> 2    12345 2014-10-01    200 2014-10-04   150
> 4    33344 2014-10-03    500 2014-10-04    50
> 5    33344 2014-10-03    500 2014-10-05   504
> 6    33344 2014-10-03    500 2014-10-06   332
> 7    33344 2014-10-03    500 2014-10-08    56
> 10   66554 2014-10-10    660 2014-10-11   400
> 11   66554 2014-10-10    660 2014-10-12   150
> 12   66554 2014-10-10    660 2014-10-13   800
> ```